# Access required error while Saving SharePoint site as template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We are getting

> "Sorry, you don't have access."

error while trying to save a SharePoint site as template in Microsoft Office 365.

[image: Access Required - Sorry, you don't have access.]

We tried setting "Allow users to run custom script on personal site" and "Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites" options from SharePoint Online Admin Center as mentioned in the article: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/06/fix-sorry-you-dont-have-access-error-on-save-site-as-template.html

Also we waited for more than 24 hours now to take the effect. But we are still getting the same error.

Is there anything else we need to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to run the powershell command to allow custom script on this site:

```
Set-SPOSite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! After running the above script we were able to save the site as template. We thought setting the option from SharePoint Admin center would work.